# Stream multiple variables on one line?

Tags: c++, shortcut, cin

```
int  num1, num2, num3, num4;
```

This is the only way I've figured out how to do this:

```
cin >> num1; cin >> num2; cin >> num3;
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
cin >> num1, num2, num3;
```

This would be helpful for me to complete assignments and save lines of code without looking sloppy.

Comment: Have you tried `cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;`?

Comment: `This would be helpful for me to comlete assignments and save lines of code without looking sloppy.` In the real world it's recommended to not put everything on one line. Certainly having commands on separate lines is rather more readable than sloppy.

Comment: i second DeiDei, for example many guidelines advocate declaring only a single variable per line, reasons to do so is readability, easier diffs with version control and less confusion with pointers. So actually `int  num1, num2, num3, num4;` should be 4 lines. Don't be lazy on typing, it doesn't pay off. Code is much more often read than it is written

Comment: I guess the thing is I don't know what actual "real world code" looks like that arent examples.

Answer (score 6):

`>>` returns a reference to the same `istream`, so you can chain them:

```cpp
cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is:

```
cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;
```